# Natural deduction with coq assistant prover

Tags: coq, natural-deduction

I want to mimic natural deduction proofs in coq ; for instance the proof I made for "A /\ B -> B /\ A" is for now

```
Theorem commute_and : A /\ B -> B /\ A.
Proof.
    intro hAB.
    elim hAB.
    split.
    auto.
    auto.
Qed.
```

I am trying to obtain something more close to the operators elimination and introduction axioms.

1/ First part of the attempt : create functions for introduction and elimination of the operator 'and'

I tried :

```
Definition elim_and_r ( C : Prop) : Prop:=
    match C with
    |  A /\ B => A
end.
```

But Coq doesn't understand the pattern   "A /\ B" (I also tried " A && B"
and "and A B" and I also added "Require Import Coq.Init.Logic." at the beginning of the code).

2/ Second part :

I tried to use the theorem proj1 of the library Coq.Init.Logic with

```
Theorem commute_and_V2 : A /\ B -> B /\ A.
Proof.
    intro hAB.
    apply proj1.
```

but it gives to me "Unable to find an instance for the variable B." (if I try "apply proj1 hAB", an error occurs as well).

If I can fix the step one, I would like to use `apply elim_and_r hAB.`
but is hAB even of type Prop ?

You can see that I am a bit lost at deferent levels... It is true I'm beginning in Coq, so, sorry if it is dumb questions.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what your question is.

Comment: Also your function `elim_and_r` isn’t going to give you what you think it is.  By returning a `Prop` you are returning something which could be true or false, and there is no logical connection between the input `Prop` and output `Prop`.

Comment: Maybe look at the term proofs generated with `Show Proof.`. Or (and I hate to point you to another system, but) [Section 3.3 of Theorem proving in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/propositions_and_proofs.html#propositional-logic) focuses on term proofs for propositional logic, and you can easily see the connection to natural deduction-style elim and intro rules.  (I imagine there is a similar Coq reference, but I don’t know it.)

Comment: @JasonRute I already did it with Lean ; in fact I am working in translating Latex proof into proof assistants one. Since I could do with Lean, I wanted to do it with Coq, and see the differences

Comment: @JasonRute Basically, I have a tree with nodes (Vector_of_propositions, intro/elim_operator) and I want to convert it automatically in Coq

Comment: @JasonRute you are probably right : my question is a bit fuzzy, but why elim_and_r generate an error, to start with ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138826/discussion-between-jason-rute-and-netchaiev).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Based on our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138826/discussion-between-jason-rute-and-netchaiev), I've figured out what you are asking for.)

Since you know natural deduction and Lean, you already know what the natural deduction rules look like in Lean, e.g. here are the [and elimination rules in Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#and.elim_left):

```
theorem and.elim_left {a b : Prop} (h : a ∧ b) : a
theorem and.elim_right {a b : Prop} (h : a ∧ b) : b
```

The `and.intro` rule is automatically generated as:

```
constructor and.intro : ∀ {a b : Prop}, a → b → a ∧ b
```

The corresponding rules in Coq are in [Coq.Init.Logic](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html#and):

```ml
Inductive and (A B:Prop) : Prop := conj : A -> B -> A /\ B
Section Conjunction.
  Variables A B : Prop.
  Theorem proj1 : A /\ B -> A.
  Theorem proj2 : A /\ B -> B.
End Conjunction.
```

Notice the right-and-elimination-rule `proj2` doesn't look anything like your `elim_and_r`.

Here is a tactic proof of your theorem using these rules.  Your mistake is that you forgot to apply the intro rule `conj` where you needed to.

```ml
Variables A B : Prop.
Theorem commute_and_V2 : A /\ B -> B /\ A.
Proof.
    intro hAB.
    apply conj.           (* and intro rule *)
    - apply (proj2 hAB).  (* and elim right*)
    - apply (proj1 hAB).  (* and elim left *)
Qed.
```

Also, by using `Show Proof.` we can see the term proof:

```ml
(fun hAB : A /\ B => conj (proj2 hAB) (proj1 hAB))
```